# "Route [login] not defined." after hosting. laravel 5.7 but working on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, hosting

//web.php

```
     Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/login', 'AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');

     Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
         Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
     });
```

//admincontroller.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Auth;
    use Session;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
        public function login(Request $request)
        {
           if($request->isMethod('post')) {
               $data = $request->input();
               if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],
               'password'=>$data['password'], 'admin'=>'1'])) {
                   return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
               } else {
                   return redirect()->route('admin.login')
                   ->with('flash_message_error', 'Invalid Access Credentials');
               }
           }
       return view ('backend.admin_login');
    }
}
```

//Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index'); 
Route::get('404',['as'=>'404','uses'=>'ErrorHandlerController@errorCode404']); 
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); 
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/login', 'AdminController@login')->name('admin.login'); 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){ 
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard'); 
 }); 
Route::get('/logout', 'AdminController@logout')->name('adminlogout');
```

Please help me.... I have tried a lot, but have not been able to find any real bugs. It works fine on localhost . Any Laravel 5.7 geeks here.

Waiting for your help.. Thanks In advance.

Comment: where are you hosting your project?

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace? A route with name `login` is not used anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Jerodev full stacktrace mean? what i need to show

Comment: Laravel 7.2? Latest version is 5.7. Or do you mean PHP 7.2?

Comment: @Jerodev Show your full web.php file. We don't see any login routes

Comment: oh sry mistake php 7.2 laravel 5.7 @Ruub

Comment: also, what isn't working? the form or the view? please explain further what is wrong and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: this error tell you that there is not a route with name [login], check any call for `{{ route('login') }} ` in your **view**

Comment: @CreativeNb  edit your question with the view

Comment: i've edited the question with the routes list for you @CreativeNb

Comment: @CreativeNb Is laravel successfully opening in your hosting? I mean, other routes are working fine? or this is the error is occurring when you are trying to access the website ?

Comment: @FahimUddin yes other routes are working fine , only the problem is i am not getting log into my dashboard, and all login process works well on local server.

Comment: @FahimUddin checkout www.nabindc.com.np a simple portfolio and blogging site

Comment: @AlaaEddineChebil this call is in default login.blade.php file of laravel but i am working through my own login, does that matter?

Comment: thanks Nabil this problem was solved but, i am redirecting back into login page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default 'auth' middleware then there should be a route named 'login'. But you only have 'admin.login' page. My guess is the problem is in middleware.

Check the 'app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php' file. By default, it is like this,

```
 protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

change `return route('login')` to `return route('admin.login')`

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: yes it solved the problem of route login not found, but i am redirected back to login page instead of redirecting to dashboard.

Comment: You need to login. Without logging in you won"t be able to access the dashboard. Check if your input data is correct. For debug you may put dd(request()) and match it with your database.